# Conditions to play co-op campaign in StarCraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

I started playing StarCraft 2 back in november 2017 as it became free to play.

I am enjoying the game so far, but it looks like I am unable to play the co-op missions. Maybe it's because noone is queueing for the same difficulty, for the same map (I chose "Random" to make it easier), maybe it's because I'm launching it alone, or maybe it's because my internet is so bad (I have like 300ms average ping on multiplayer)

In short, there's just the "Loading" number who doesn't rise.

So, in order to play the co-op missions, should I try inviting a friend into a party or my internet is just unable to handle it?

Comment: What loading number do you mean? The Streaming or waiting for players?

Comment: @MartinH. the streaming

Comment: Is it only in Coop or do you also have the long wait times in versus?

Comment: @MartinH. it's rather long in versus as well, but I can play after 2 minutes maximum, but I could never play the co-op even after 10 minutes doing nothing but wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information we have it seems your connection is just to slow.

Before you can queue for the game sc2 will stream some data (around 200-300 MB for me)

Playing with a buddy will not help you with that problem.

The bad part is that after the game finds a mate for you it will stream another batch of data. That might cause extremely long loading screens for you.

Comment: then, I'll keep training the main races in versus and wait for when I can afford a better ISP